# How to increase react vr frame rate

Tags: javascript, optimization, react-360

## Background

I am building a proof of concept for a webvr project. After attending the react amsterdam conference last month and seeing react vr in action I thought this would be a good place to start.

I have setup a demo page [here](http://vr-poc.thesecretpages.nl/). It's just an image added to the hello world example.

Inside the Chrome browser (desktop & mobile) it looks fine, not choppy. The I visit the page with my gear vr. When in the samsung browser window the app runs fine but once I press the <kbd>view in vr</kbd> button (*bottom left*) the frame rate drops quite a lot. Enough to give you a headache after a few minutes. I have the same choppy experience with the react-vr examples [here](https://github.com/nikgraf/webvr-experiments)

## Specs

I am using

- Gear vr
- Samsung Internet
- Samsung galaxy S6
- Android 6

The mobile device is a little old now (over a year) maybe that is causing the issue but it works very smooth before entering vr mode.

## Question

Is there a way to force more processing power out of a device (Something like adding `will-change: transform;` or `transform: translateZ(0);`)?

*or*

Is this purely a limitation of the hardware?

*or*

Is react-vr adding too much overhead, is there a way to optimise? I do have a very smooth experience with the three.js cubes [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webvr_cubes.html)